# how do i remove holidays from timeline view of FullCalendar.js

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to find a way to remove some days from the timeline view of full calendar because they are company holidays. like removing the 4th of July, memorial day etc.  how do I do this?

Comment: It's hard to entirely remove them from the display, but you can easily mark them as unavailable or whatever -perhaps by using Background Events, or the businessHours feature.

Comment: the problem is its on the time line view. not the regular views. we are building a gantt chart like display and need to remove non workdays that are not weekends.

Comment: i should make it clear this is not a timegrid or daygrid view, its the premium timeline view

Comment: Yes that was clear already. The answer is the same in each case.

Comment: can you explain how you would do that? i do not see any way to specify business hours for one specific date, nor do i see a way for using the background events to block out time. im new at this, im obviously missing something here.  if there is a way to specify business hours for specific dates that would be great. btw we are using the react interface in this project

Comment: You're right businessHours is more for a continuous pattern of recurring dates. However a background event is just an event, but displayed differently. So if you create an event feed of holiday days, and set it to show them all as background events that will work. If you additionally want to stop people creating events on those dates, or dragging events onto those dates, that can be controlled through the appropriate options / callbacks - there are examples in the docs.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to entirely remove them from the display via the API unfortunately, but you can easily mark them as unavailable or whatever - perhaps by using a feed of Background Events, with one event for each holiday. You can maybe generate them from your server, or there are public calendars online containing the official holidays of different countries, which you might be able to use as the source.

A background event is the same as a regular event, except its display mode is changed - for example:

```
{
  start: '2022-06-01T10:00:00',
  end: '2022-06-01T16:00:00',
  display: 'background'
}
```

If you additionally want to stop people creating events on those dates, or dragging events onto those dates, that can be controlled through the appropriate options / callbacks - there are examples in the fullCalendar documentation, such as this one which will prevent a user creating a new event on top of a background event:

```
selectOverlap: function(event) {
  return event.rendering === 'background';
}
```

References:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap